# Unsupervised Learning for regression analysis

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, unsupervised-learning

I am a geophysics student and I am trying to predict shear wave velocity which is numerical data. I feel since it is numerical data it'd be regression analysis but the problem I have now is that I don't have a shear wave log I can use as a target which then makes the project unsupervised, How do I go about it, please?

I want to if it's possible to predict numerical data because I have tried picking out random logs I feel will predict it but how do I check the accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution inhere for you is to make data out of the signal data. I was also working on similar kind of problem where I was to predict the intensity of fall and data that I got was signal data having x,y,z axis. I managed to solve the problem by initially creating the data using clustering methodology according to my use case.Now since I have supervised data I proceded with futher analysis and predictions.

Comment: wow, can you share the work with me, I'd like to go through it.

Comment: I am afraid I can't that code is being used by my firm,can't just share it. Feel free to connect with me over linkedIN if you need some help we can surely figure things out https://www.linkedin.com/in/sumit-mandal-753692130/